# How to parse JSON array in Go

Tags: arrays, json, go, slice

How to parse a string (which is an array) in Go using json package?

```golang
type JsonType struct{
    Array []string
}

func main(){
    dataJson = `["1","2","3"]`
    arr := JsonType{}
    unmarshaled := json.Unmarshal([]byte(dataJson), &arr.Array)
    log.Printf("Unmarshaled: %v", unmarshaled)
}
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The [return value](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) of `Unmarshal` is an [error](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#error), and this is what you are printing out:

```
// Return value type of Unmarshal is error.
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(dataJson), &arr)
```

You can get rid of the `JsonType` as well and just use a slice:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    dataJson := `["1","2","3"]`
    var arr []string
    _ = json.Unmarshal([]byte(dataJson), &arr)
    log.Printf("Unmarshaled: %v", arr)
}

// prints out:
// 2009/11/10 23:00:00 Unmarshaled: [1 2 3]
```

Code on play: https://play.golang.org/p/GNWlylavam

Background: Passing in a pointer allows `Unmarshal` to reduce (or get entirely rid of) memory allocations. Also, in a processing context, the caller may reuse the same value to repeatedly - saving allocations as well.

Answer (score 12):

**Note:** This answer was written before the question was edited. In the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/38867692/1) `&arr` was passed to `json.Unmarshal()`:

```
unmarshaled := json.Unmarshal([]byte(dataJson), &arr)
```

---

You pass the address of `arr` to [`json.Unmarshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) to unmarshal a JSON array, but `arr` is not an array (or slice), it is a struct value.

Arrays can be unmarshaled into Go arrays or slices. So pass `arr.Array`:

```
dataJson := `["1","2","3"]`
arr := JsonType{}
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(dataJson), &arr.Array)
log.Printf("Unmarshaled: %v, error: %v", arr.Array, err)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/0cG8ZIyK-0)):

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 Unmarshaled: [1 2 3], error: <nil>
```

Of course you don't even need the `JsonType` wrapper, just use a simple `[]string` slice:

```
dataJson := `["1","2","3"]`
var s []string
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(dataJson), &s)
```

Comment: I forgot that I pass the address, and thought it returned the parsed array, so that why the result was <nil> because it was the value of the error, shame on me.

Comment: @kingSlayer You have to pass the address of the variable so the `json` package can unmarshal right into your variable. The result doesn't need to be returned, but the optional error have to be.

Comment: So my problem was that I printed out the value of error and not the pointed value of the arr.Array, that was the confusion for me, Thanks.

Comment: @kingSlayer Yeah, you edited your question, but in your [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/38867692/1)  you passed `arr` which results in an error.